# subdomains share the same source

Tags: .htaccess, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I have 2 subdomains,

```
a.domain.com 
b.domain.com
```

I want both of them share the same source--

```
domain.com/source.html
```

I found the two subdomains can not share same source, request headers origin can not be changed dynamaticaly, I spent hours without any solution, could you give me some instruction? following is my htaccess script

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
```

index.html file in both two subdomain have totally same script

```
<base href='domain.com'>
<div></div>
<script>
  $("div").load("source.html");
</script>
```

Hope I have my problem clear, thanks in advance for help.

Comment: why are you not pointing both subdomains to same folder on your server in your apache config?

Comment: @Kristof Feys, thank you very much,It is a good idea, I am curious how to share the same file.